# How to merge two files with unique IDs?

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files. File1 and File2.

File1:

```
1 a
2 b
```

File2:

```
1 a
2 c
3 d
```

I would like to generate a file that has the following:

```
1 a
2 c
3 d
```

The lines that File2 has either inserted or updated into File1, sort of how the UPSERT feature works in SQL.

Comment: So what happens to the `b` value in this case in the "merged" file?

Comment: 2 has b in File1 but c in File2, so the new value is getting set from File2. (Insert if the ID is not there, update if the ID is there)

Comment: Given these rules, wouldn't file 2 always be the same as your desired result?  so if 4 existed in file 1 since it didn't exist in file 2 it should be deleted... so again file 2 is the desired result.  I don't understand the point of merge...  So the script would be to copy file2 replacing file1... `cp -fHip File1 file2`

Comment: Exactly. You might wanna provide an actual "merging" scenario for us to be able to understand your problem a bit better.

Comment: will this solve your problem? `awk '{a[$1]=$2}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' f1 f2`

Comment: xQbert, the example I gave was not quite right, there are cases when the original file has more lines than the new file, so it would not be simply overwriting with the later, I really need the merge, and Fredrik gave the right answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here, since question is a bit vague. Anyway, here's something in awk that just uses the first value as a `key` to store the 2nd value. 2nd value always overwrites content in array if the key is found multiple times:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$0}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' f1 f2
1 a
2 c
3 d
```

EDIT: The new version takes an arbitrary wide file instead of being tied to two fields.

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help! Keep posting them questions and think about ambiguity :-)

Comment: Do you know how could I print out all of the field from f2? Thank you in advance.